# Reason: image not found macos application

Tags: macos, qt, dyld, otool, macdeployqt

I am deploying qt application for macos so in order to create .app I am using macdeployqt tool.

My problem is that when I run the application I get this error:

```
dyld: Library not loaded: @rpath/QtWebEngineWidgets.framework/Versions/5/QtWebEngineWidgets
```

Referenced from: /Users/raulsanchez/Documents/workspace/Myapp.app/Contents/MacOS/Myapp
  Reason: image not found

I have checked with otool and i have this:

```
@rpath/QtWebEngineWidgets.framework/Versions/5/QtWebEngineWidgets (compatibility version 5.9.0, current version 5.9.7)
```

If it matters I have used macdeployqt with option -use-debug-libs and -no-strip

Could anyone help me on this?

Thanks in advance

Comment: If a project is done with QML, when deploying with `macdeployqt`, the option `-qmldir=...` is used to get all the Qml dependencies. There might be a similar option for **web-widgets** too

Comment: Did the QtWebEngineWidgets lib get copied into your @rpath?

Comment: Yes, I have the framework in Framework folder inside the bundle. Also I have defined rpath as:QMAKE_LFLAGS += -Wl,-rpath,@loader_path/../,-rpath,@executable_path/../,-rpath,@executable_path/../Frameworks

Answer (score 0):

I finally found the solution. Since I was using debug version of the Frameworks '_debug' suffix was being appended. That was the reason why it was not being found